# step down switching frequency

Tags: power-supply, led, current, driver, rectifier

If I have a power supply that outputs 32V,7A and I need to power an LED that requires 24V-2.8A, can i use this step-down module to power up the LED?

```
Module Properties: non-isolated constant current and voltage module
**Rectification: non-synchronous rectification**
Input voltage: 5V-32V
Output voltage: 0.8V-30V
Output current: adjustable maximum 5A
**Switching frequency: 300KHz**
Output ripple: 50mV (max) 20M bandwidth
Load Regulation: ± 0.5%
Voltage Regulation: ± 2.5%
```

Is the switching frequency and/or the rectification a problem?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answer:

I would not use a module where Vin(max) is the same as the voltage it is being fed. I would want at least a few volts of margin (in case the primary power supply goes a little high).

Even if the absolute maximum rating is not necessarily reached (the statement above does not state if this is the recommended maximum or absolute maximum), the device will be under more stress and will not necessarily last as long than one rated for a higher voltage.

In addition, when doing LED drivers, make sure that LED OPEN sensing is incorporated.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

> Is the switching frequency and/or the rectification a problem?

Not per se, but non-synchronous rectification results in lower efficiency than synchronous rectification, and anything wireless that works at or around 300kHz will suffer some EM interference (only [DGPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_GPS) shows up after a quick search).

Make sure that it can set a current limit while allowing the voltage to float to whatever value required though, or you're likely to be unhappy.

Answer (score 0):

> can i use this step-down module to power up the LED?

Yup.

> Is the switching frequency and/or the rectification a problem?

Nope.

That said, you would be running this converter right at its maximum input voltage.  It is still within spec, but that's OK only if you are really sure the input won't go higher.  You could put a diode in series with the input to drop the voltage a little.  If so, it should be rated for 2.5 A and 2 W continuous.

The switching frequency is of little interest.  That gives you some idea what the predominant frequency of the output ripple will be, but you can't rely on that.